# How to fix pytorch 'RuntimeError: Expected object of type torch.cuda.LongTensor but found type torch.LongTensor'

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm

I'm trying to get [this](https://github.com/jamie-murdoch/ContextualDecomposition) code running using FloydHub's GPU.
When I run the *train.py* script under *train_model* folder, I'm getting the RuntimeError mentioned.

Here is the full traceback:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "./train_model/train.py", line 79, in 
>   answer = model(batch)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 477, in **call**
>   result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
>   File "/floyd/home/train_model/model.py", line 29, in forward
>   vecs = self.embed(batch.text)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 477, in **call**
>   result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/sparse.py", line 110, in forward
>   self.norm_type, self.scale_grad_by_freq, self.sparse)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 1110, in embedding
>   return torch.embedding(weight, input, padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
>   RuntimeError: Expected object of type torch.cuda.LongTensor but found type torch.LongTensor for argument #3 'index'

I understand that parts of code are using GPU and other parts aren't but not knowing how to identify these and get all of the code to run on GPU.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The error comes while forward function is being called. As the error says, the forward function "Expected object of type torch.cuda.LongTensor", I reckon that your input `batch` is still in the CPU, and needs to be transferred to the cuda device.

I feel that you already know how to do it, but if you don't, please read-up https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html#training-on-gpu.

Hope it helps, let me know if you need more help. :)

Comment: How do we send `batch` to GPU? I've tried both `batch = batch.cuda()` and `batch.to(device)`. But they don't work as there aren't attributes like that

Comment: Shouldn't be the case? Before calling forward function, can you put a statement `print(type(batch))` and let me know if it is a tensor or numpy array or something else?

Comment: This is what `type(batch)` gives `<class 'torchtext.data.batch.Batch'>`

Comment: The input to the forward function needs to Pytorch tensor, whereas, batch is an object of class torchtext.data.batch.Batch. Your input data must be one of attributes of the object instance `batch`. Generally, torchtext, the attribute containing input is name `src` and should be accessed as `batch.src` in your case. Let me know.

Comment: This is the list of attributes for `torchtext.data.batch`: https://torchtext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#torchtext.data.Batch 
Not sure which one of these is a tensor

Comment: `dataset` is the attribute you should look for, I will get free in a few hours, and vcan try looking at it too.

Comment: I tried that too. But `dataset` isn't a tensor. It is `<class 'torchtext.datasets.sst.SST'>`. Getting an AttributeError for that: https://pastebin.com/4mtAThJL

Comment: Not that I meant that you use it directly but dataset objects somewhere would be containing your input. I will have to look into your code, carefully, will reply in sometime.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your time and effort on this! :)

Comment: [@Anant Mittal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12266923/anant-mittal)
I'm totally stuck... :(
Could you help with figuring this out please...

Comment: Hey there, sorry, I am a bit occupied at my work.Can you me remind me once ai.with.anant@gmail.com, would try best finding time to help you once I go back home.

Answer (score 0):

i resolved this error by running my code in Tensorflow 2 , so it might be a TF version issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).